# 2 like characters in same position

Tags: python, string, function

I am trying to return the number of positions in which 2 strings have the same character.

Tried code:

```
    def matches(stringOne, stringTwo):
    if stringOne or stringTwo == " ": 
        return None
    else:
       n=0
       count=0
       if stringOne[n] == stringTwo[n]:
           count=count+1
       else:
           pass
       n=n+1
       return count
```

Example:

```
   matches = matches("abcd", "xbade")
   print matches
   2
```

Thanks! :)

And no, it's not a homework.

No zip functions please. I'm not trying to use Python built in functions.

Comment: You're close. Consider the case where stringOne and stringTwo have different lengths. After the comparison, you'll have to check to see if you have reached the end of either of the two strings. if so, return.

Answer (score 1):

You can use a generator expression with `zip` to iterate through the strings for a letter-by-letter comparison

```
def matches(stringOne, stringTwo):
    return sum(1 for i,j in zip(stringOne, stringTwo) if i == j)

>>> matches("abcd", "xbade")
2
>>> matches('dictionary', 'dibpionabc')
6
```

If you don't want to use Python's `zip` function

```
def matches(stringOne, stringTwo):
    shorter = min(len(stringOne), len(stringTwo))
    same = 0
    for i in range(shorter):
        same += stringOne[i] == stringTwo[i]
    return same
```

Although even that method uses `min`, `len`, and `range`. You are really tying your hands behind your back if you refuse to use the built-in functions of a language.

Comment: It's a bad idea to use range. Use enumerate as I did in my answer checking if index and value are both the same.

Comment: @MalikBrahimi Well if you are going to use `enumerate` you might as well use `zip`, but OP doesn't want to use that for some reason. And using `range` isn't really a "bad idea" because I made sure to use the shorter of the two lengths.

Comment: Yes, I was trying to give the OP more of a function rather than a single statement of a generator.

Answer (score 0):

I would use a generator as Cyber suggested, otherwise change your function up:

```
def matches(a, b):
    total = 0

    for i, j in enumerate(a):
        for x, y in enumerate(b):
            if i == x and j == y:
                total += 1

    return total
```

Answer (score 0):

```
a = 'abcd'
b = 'xbddea'
def matches(astr, bstr):
    total = 0
    i = 0
    while i<len(astr) and i<len(bstr):
        if astr[i] == bstr[i]:
            total += 1
        i += 1
    return total
print(matches(a,b)
```

Comment: Only two builtins used here, print() and len(). len() from what I remember is just an int look up not a counting of chars each use. i<len(astr) and not i<=len as sequences are zero based indexed